# PHP.exe deletes after script execution

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, libpng

I've got some magic here.

XAMPP, PHP 7.1

I've got some script for wp-cli for Wordpress. Nothing serious there, I just creating users and making avatars for them.
It has been working several times without errors, beside one:
**libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile**

Now, algorithm - I'm executing command

> wp eval-file con_emp_create.php

It throws me an error about libpng after several users created, and when i start it again magic happens - again after some iteratons script crashes and php.exe disappearing from xampp/php folder right in front of my eyes.
What is it and how can I solve this problem with libpng?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eyH0E9Uz  - plugin script

Comment: Please do not details in comments to the question, post it into the question itself. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_.

Comment: And please be more precise in your question. What does "php.exe removes from xampp/php folder" _exactly_? What is removed?

Comment: there's a hell interface for posting links to pastebin. after 5 minutes trying I post it here

Comment: file php.exe removing, deletes, destroys itself, it doesn't exist there anymore

Comment: I see such thing for the first time for 6 years of web development, so i decide to ask it here

Comment: The code you posted does not do that, must be some other component of your set. But a general hint: a php script should _never_ be able to modify itself. You should take care of that using correct file system permissions for such resources.

Comment: About pasting: can't follow there. Using off-site resources like `pastebin` is clearly considered off-topic here and even if that were a good idea I fail to see why you cannot post that link inside the question instead of as a comment.